# AFNetworking with request error code 999

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, rubymotion

I'm new to objective-c and i'm having a hard time with a AFNetworking.

So the thing is that i want to make a simple POST request to a server who will send me back a salt.
I'v make a simple app, in order to test my request but i don't understand why i'm getting the error code 999.

Here a sample of my code.

```
+ (void)simpleRequest; {
    NSURL *mailserver = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://localhost:4443/"];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithBaseURL:mailserver];
    manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = TRUE;
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": @"testtest"};

    [manager POST:@"api/v0/login/salt" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

I' have link this code to a simple Button which's calling this function.

I have an other app, in ruby motion which's work fined with this function i can get the response without any error. But with this simple app i can't do any request, they all returned this error code 999.

> Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://localhost:4443/api/v0/login/salt,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://localhost:4443/api/v0/login/salt}

So i'm really wondering what i'm doing wrong, anyone can help me on this ?
Thanks

EDIT:

Is it the good way for saving the manager in a property or am i doing something wrong ?
If it's the good way, this seems to not work 
Thanks for the help

> .h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) AFHTTPSessionManager *session;
```

> .m file

```
@synthesize session;
- (IBAction)log:(id)sender {
NSURL *mailserver = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://localhost:4443/"];

self.session = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc]initWithBaseURL:mailserver];
self.session.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = TRUE;
self.session.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
self.session.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": @"testtest"};

[self.session POST:@"api/v0/login/salt" parameters:parameters success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: It's showing that your URL is error...maybe should convert localhost to your IP address?

Comment: And sometime the params will be in the request body and that param field is nil: like [https://localhost:4443/api/v0/login/salt?username=testtest](https://localhost:4443/api/v0/login/salt?username=testtest)

Comment: I just tried but it doesn't work, at least thanks for the help

Comment: In my case it should be a request like that 'https://localhost:4443/api/v0/login/salt', Which's work fined in my other app

Comment: i did some searched in Google and they said its because of previous one request hasn't complete and the other one sends , thus u get the Cancelled error

Comment: ah ok, but it's weird because this is the only request that i'v done.

Comment: Still unsolve, maybe i have to initialize something before making a request ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case iOS 9 SDK's "**App transport security**" cause **AFNetworking** **error code : -999**.
If you're trying to reach a server that doesn't have a SSL add keys like screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: This should not be an accepted answer anymore. As of iOS 10, allowing arbitrary loads requires a review from Apple and specific permission to do so. The better answer is to use ATS to allow loads to HTTP locations by using exceptions. View this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http, for the real solution to this problem.

Answer (score 25):

In my case iOS 10 SDK's caused AFNetworking error code -999. If you're trying to reach a server that has SSL and you don't want to check it out, add some privacy Policy to Afnetworking

```
AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;

[securityPolicy setValidatesDomainName:NO];
```

Comment: A little more context, like where to assign this security policy, or whether it's a singleton, etc, would be helpful. This answer by itself isn't really enough.

Comment: Fwiw, the premise of this answer is useful -- setting the security policy _on the session manger_ does help (at least in my case).

Comment: _sessionManager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:_sessionConfiguration];
        
AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
[securityPolicy setValidatesDomainName:NO];
_sessionManager.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;

Comment: I'm getting an error about `AFSSLPinningModeNone`  being ambiguous (AFNetworking 3.1) (solved it using `[AFSecurityPolicy defaultPolicy]` which internally calls the same thing anyway).

Comment: This didn't entirely work, getting this warning now: "In order to validate a domain name for self signed certificates, you MUST use pinning".

Answer (score 12):

That's error -999, not 999.  That is `NSURLErrorCancelled`.  Your request has been cancelled before it can be completed.

Looking at your code, you aren't retaining the `AFHTTPSessionManager *manager` anywhere.  This means that the manager will be disposed as soon as `+simpleRequest` returns.  I'm guessing that this is what is cancelling your request.

You need to save the manager so that it lives for the full duration of the request.  Save it in a property somewhere.

Comment: I think i have correctly save the manager but it's still failing, did i have miss something ?

Comment: @xikimay then it's because the instance owning your property is deinitialised before the response gets back. A hack might be to call the manager within the block (through a `Log()`) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your API endpoint indicates to a secure connection:

> http**S**://localhost:4443/api/v0/login/salt

Just try it just in case, maybe it repeats your situation.

In my case, **this was a typo** in the API manager code. Which from the part can be said is connected with App Transport Security Settings.

Just changed the protected protocol from `httpS://` to `http://` and the error:

> NSURLErrorDomain Code = -999 "cancelled"

was gone and **it all worked**!

+And also if you had a similar problem. Be sure to **discuss this with a backend specialist** who deals with the server or API configuration for your application. This means that the server does not have valid security certificates. Perhaps you still need a secure connection. Or this specialist can again configure everything back from `http://` to `httpS://`, and I'm not sure (did not check) whether this will work again when in the code you are already using a non-secure `http://` connection.

Answer (score 0):

[Original OP question may not mention Cordova but this link was very high in the search result when Googling this issue]

For my **Cordova project (or similar)**, turns out it was a **plugin issue**. Make sure you're not missing any plugins and make sure they're installed properly without issue.

Easiest way to verify this is simply to start fresh by **recreating the Cordova project** (`cordova create <path>`) along with the required platforms (`cordova platform add <platform name>`) and add each plugin with the verbose flag (--verbose) so that you can see if anything went wrong in the console log while the plugin is being downloaded, added to project and installed for each platform (`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device --verbose`)

Recap:
`cordova create <path>`
`cordova platform add <platform name>`
`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device --verbose`