# HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89]) for Task in iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, urlsession

I'm using URLSession to perform a datatask, when I run it on iOS 11, I get a console error:

```
HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89]) for Task <68809C58-C6A7-4F10-86A4-81396D8B18CF>.<2>
```

Any thought on what's causing it, or how to fix it?

Comment: I have the exact same issue on iPhone SE (only)

Comment: I have the same issue on all iOS 11 simulators. Not using any http URL in this scenario, only https. But I do have NSAllowsArbitraryLoads set to YES.

Comment: This answer sort of explains what is the error code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16076142/4160079
But no clue as to why requests are cancelled on iOS 11 only.

Comment: I am also getting same error on iOS11, However everything is working fine on iOS10.

Comment: Same error in Iphone 5s with ios 11, any update ?

Comment: i got this when Downloading zip file. (AFNetworking, iPhone 7, iOS 11)

Answer (score 10):

```
HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89]) for Task
```

`Error -999` means `NSURLErrorCancelled`, your request has been canceled before completion. According to the [apple developer blog](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/15705#15705), there are few changes with `ATS` (likely that your server is using one of legacy crypto facilities that have been removed in iOS 11.) So give a try and implement the [connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlconnectiondelegate/1417135-connection?language=objc) and see if your server raises authentication challenge if yes then here is something we need to handle.

I hope it will help!

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when trying to do the HTTPS

Request has been canceled before completion
In my case the SSL Certificated was not installed properly.

Check your SSL certificate if your using one.
Task <1> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])
Task <>.<1> finished with error - code: -999

Comment: I have added certificate properly but still its giving HTTP load failed error , any suggetion?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your internet connection is working. It happened to me that it's working in the simulator, but got the error on iphoneSE. I found it that my iphoneSE internet connection had a problem.