# NSURLErrorDomain error -999 in Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uiwebview

I am working on Xamarin iOS platform while loading a URL in webview I am getting the error

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)

I have also added the `NSAppTransportSecurity` key in info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

But it is not working. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> This error occurs due to a request is made before the previous request
>   of WebView is completed

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16076142/6866139)

Just ignore the error in the `LoadFailed(UIWebView webView, NSError error)` delegate method.

Try this code

```
public override void LoadFailed(UIWebView webView, NSError error)
{
    if (error.Code == -999) 
    {
      // Show some alert or just ignore the error
    }
}
```

Also, check you have a proper network connection

Hope it will solve your problem