# How to work with AFNetwroking without SSL certificate in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, ssl, afnetworking

Web service were working fine. All of a sudden webservice started throwing NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled".

We tried to get the response in POSTMAN and response was same. We disabled the SSL certificate option in POSTMAN and server started responding. Android uses the same web services and its working fine with them. iOS we have integrated AFNetwroking to get consume web service. I have googled around and it set the  "self.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;""
However still the response from server to iOS device is NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled.

Is there anyway where we don't allow the webservice to validate with SSL certificate.

Comment: Have you added App transport security into your plist?

Comment: @dipesh-pokhrel : Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073519/nsurlerrordomain-error-code-999-in-ios I don't think it got anything to do with SSL

Comment: I have mentioned earlier that through POSTMAN we could get the response if ssl certificate authentication is disabled. Just want to know is there any way by which we can disable the SSL authentication while using AFNetworking.