# When push webview, there is a NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

When the app push a webview, the console print an error NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999.There are some code about WebViewbridge on the html page

> 2018-05-01 10:34:54.189185+0800 FakeICBCBank[39093:7872256] webViewDidStartLoad
>   2018-05-01 10:34:54.728493+0800 FakeICBCBank[39093:7872355] WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process FakeICBCBank
>   2018-05-01 10:34:54.729007+0800 FakeICBCBank[39093:7872355] WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)
>   2018-05-01 10:34:54.729512+0800 FakeICBCBank[39093:7872355] WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
>   2018-05-01 10:34:54.752704+0800 FakeICBCBank[39093:7872256] webViewDidStartLoad
>   2018-05-01 10:34:54.767676+0800 FakeICBCBank[39093:7872336] TIC TCP Conn Failed [2:0x60400017a7c0]: 12:8 Err(-65554)
>   2018-05-01 10:34:54.771145+0800 FakeICBCBank[39093:7872329] Task <66500A32-BB5E-47D2-9AB4-80D458C4D148>.<0> HTTP load failed (error code: -1003 [12:8])
>   2018-05-01 10:34:54.775590+0800 FakeICBCBank[39093:7872256] didFailLoadWithError Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=[https://**bridge_loaded**/](https://__bridge_loaded__/), NSErrorFailingURLKey=[https://**bridge_loaded**/](https://__bridge_loaded__/)}
>   2018-05-01 10:34:54.781458+0800 FakeICBCBank[39093:7872256] webViewDidFinishLoad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSURLErrorDomain error code -999 in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073519/nsurlerrordomain-error-code-999-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry ,maybe i found the reason.
1.write the code follow ,resgist the bridge after add the webview.
2.confirm the registerHandler after alloc the bridge
everything follow the example is correct