# Flutter - Google Maps not working on some iPhones (Error requesting StyleTable)

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I have configured Google Maps with Flutter :

- added google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1 to pub spec.yaml
- created the API keys for Google Maps SDK for iOS and Android
- did the setup for iOS and Android.
  It's working fine on Android, on iPhone 12 (iOS15), iPhone 7 (iOS14.8) but not working on iPhone SE 2nd Generation (iOS15) and iPhone 13 Pro (iOS15).
  On these devices, I get a grey screen : [image]

theses errors are logged :

```
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-TransitFocused-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-TransitFocused-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-TransitFocused-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <F25EF008-E136-4CAC-B288-E17FFC0434CF>.<2>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <F25EF008-E136-4CAC-B288-E17FFC0434CF>.<2>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Terrain-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Terrain-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Terrain-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <A691A814-567C-4410-9609-2965BDFB2D89>.<4>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <A691A814-567C-4410-9609-2965BDFB2D89>.<4>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-RoadmapSatellite-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-RoadmapSatellite-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-RoadmapSatellite-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <90C61430-6CDE-44E6-A4C2-AF76411E31F8>.<3>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <90C61430-6CDE-44E6-A4C2-AF76411E31F8>.<3>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-NavigationLowLight-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-NavigationLowLight-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-NavigationLowLight-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <B13320DA-6D28-4B93-8532-93E8F67CDA30>.<5>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <B13320DA-6D28-4B93-8532-93E8F67CDA30>.<5>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Roadmap-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Roadmap-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Roadmap-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <D68888BF-341A-4CCD-AD70-70FAE1807A1A>.<6>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <D68888BF-341A-4CCD-AD70-70FAE1807A1A>.<6>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Navigation-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Navigation-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Navigation-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <AC059CF0-90A3-4022-9B8B-54403A65BB5F>.<7>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <AC059CF0-90A3-4022-9B8B-54403A65BB5F>.<7>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-TransitFocused-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-TransitFocused-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-TransitFocused-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <5F5BBA4F-B00D-4926-B87D-493FD811C9AC>.<8>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <5F5BBA4F-B00D-4926-B87D-493FD811C9AC>.<8>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Terrain-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Terrain-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Terrain-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <EC3F530E-FEFF-48B8-BEB7-6C23DC039E11>.<9>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <EC3F530E-FEFF-48B8-BEB7-6C23DC039E11>.<9>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-RoadmapSatellite-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-RoadmapSatellite-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-RoadmapSatellite-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <BD1EC1C7-1EE0-4AF1-94B8-6FA8673A17A2>.<10>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <BD1EC1C7-1EE0-4AF1-94B8-6FA8673A17A2>.<10>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-NavigationLowLight-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-NavigationLowLight-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-NavigationLowLight-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <82883D18-4A4C-4D25-9E2C-CAE4545964F3>.<11>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <82883D18-4A4C-4D25-9E2C-CAE4545964F3>.<11>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Roadmap-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Roadmap-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Roadmap-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <DD342BE0-97EF-4592-BA5C-E043C6B164C5>.<12>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <DD342BE0-97EF-4592-BA5C-E043C6B164C5>.<12>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Navigation-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Navigation-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Navigation-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <5F688E31-E179-4A7A-BE20-05A144765B50>.<13>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <5F688E31-E179-4A7A-BE20-05A144765B50>.<13>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-TransitFocused-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-TransitFocused-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-TransitFocused-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <C07671D9-3AA8-4556-8F51-27398D6B8C6D>.<14>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <C07671D9-3AA8-4556-8F51-27398D6B8C6D>.<14>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
A StyleTable fetch/validation failed for epoch 587, https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-TransitFocused-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Terrain-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Terrain-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Terrain-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <7C568B51-E785-4FD0-B29D-71E97611249F>.<15>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <7C568B51-E785-4FD0-B29D-71E97611249F>.<15>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
A StyleTable fetch/validation failed for epoch 587, https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Terrain-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-RoadmapSatellite-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-RoadmapSatellite-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-RoadmapSatellite-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <6289A626-4B31-453A-B750-8C2C5CB6EC71>.<16>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <6289A626-4B31-453A-B750-8C2C5CB6EC71>.<16>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
A StyleTable fetch/validation failed for epoch 587, https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-RoadmapSatellite-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-NavigationLowLight-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-NavigationLowLight-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-NavigationLowLight-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <0394E81C-8A69-44F5-B96A-F1470C1119A5>.<17>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <0394E81C-8A69-44F5-B96A-F1470C1119A5>.<17>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
A StyleTable fetch/validation failed for epoch 587, https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-NavigationLowLight-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Roadmap-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Roadmap-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Roadmap-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <CA0F185D-2DFF-43BE-A6D1-458A6819FDD2>.<18>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <CA0F185D-2DFF-43BE-A6D1-458A6819FDD2>.<18>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
A StyleTable fetch/validation failed for epoch 587, https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Roadmap-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169
Error requesting StyleTable (https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Navigation-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169): Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Navigation-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Navigation-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <ED823BB1-5F12-4B75-AEFB-D4787A385B0F>.<19>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <ED823BB1-5F12-4B75-AEFB-D4787A385B0F>.<19>, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}
A StyleTable fetch/validation failed for epoch 587, https://www.gstatic.com/maps/res/CompactLegend-Navigation-NaturalFeaturesHoldBack-b42f852db1129b669a3b718d21eb3169
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NSURLErrorDomain error code -999 in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073519/nsurlerrordomain-error-code-999-in-ios)

Comment: Did you figure anything out?

Answer (score 0):

Do you unlook the things you want to do with google maps for both android and ios?

as far as I know this is necessary.