# URLSession requesting JSON array from server not working

Tags: ios, swift

```swift
guard let url =  URL(string:"https://blaaaajo.de/getHiddenUsers.php") else { return }
    
let postString = "blockedUsers=245,1150"
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);

do {
    let (responseString, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
    
    if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode([HiddenUsersModel].self, from: responseString){
        gettingBlockedUsers = false
        blockedUsers = decodedResponse
    }
    
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

the HiddenUsersModel:

```
struct HiddenUsersModel: Codable {
    var userid: Int
    var nickname: String
}
```

I'm always getting `data not valid`

The url and the POST key `blockedUsers` with the value `245,1150` is 100% correct, I'm also using this API for the web and Android app.

The code on server side doesn't get executed though, not even at the beginning of the PHP script. So no JSON response is generated.

The error I'm getting:

```
Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "Abgebrochen" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://blaaaajo.de/do_getblockedusers.php, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://blaaaajo.de/do_getblockedusers.php, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <33660134-3AEC-4416-A917-C0FC64934DB5>.<7>"
), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <33660134-3AEC-4416-A917-C0FC64934DB5>.<7>, NSLocalizedDescription=Abgebrochen}
```

according to the checked answer in [How to fix "NSURLErrorDomain error code -999" in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073519/how-to-fix-nsurlerrordomain-error-code-999-in-ios) it's `another request is made before the previous request is completed` but it's not true, when I print something before `do` then it gets printed only once

Comment: Replace `print("data not valid")` with `print("Error: \(error)")`. And replace all uses of `try?` with just `try`. Don't ignore the errors, handled them and print them. Update your question with the updates of those changes.

Comment: When I remove ? from try I get: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[HiddenUsersModel]'